# No control to new browser window while swiched to it

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

In my automation, I have to click on a button which opens a new browser instance with search results, and from that window, I have to select a video to upload. I switched to the window using:

```
driver.switch_to_window( "File Upload" )
```

In order to upload a video, I have to select the video from that window, but I can't, as there is no way to access that window. Is there any way in selenium webdriver with Ruby or some other plugin or tool I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The file upload windows are usually system windows and selenium/webdriver cannot be used to interact with it.  In Java, sendkeys is used to type the link to the file being uploaded.  You can try using an equivalent function (something that you use to type data in any textfield etc function) to directly give the link to your video file.

Hope it helps..